# Can I type backslash with UK extended keyboard (virtual) layout and US physical hardware

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

I have a US physical keyboard layout, with Windows keyboard set to UK extended keys. Is there a way to type backslash, despite the lack of the usual UK physical backslash button? On [How can I type a backslash with no backslash key?](https://superuser.com/questions/701797/how-can-i-type-a-backslash-with-no-backslash-key), one answer proposed is <kbd>Right Alt</kbd> + (what looks like \ on the physical keyboard). The latter works for me when my keyboard is set to UK, but not when it's set to extended UK (which I prefer because it gives access to accented letters easily). Does anyone have a suggestion, other than just frequently switching between keyboards?

Comment: Wouldn't US International English be a better compromise? that gives you the accents but ought to p[reserve your physical layout [Can't test as I have a UK keyboard that I use set to US Int]

Comment: Your question says "backspace" and "backslash". Please [edit] and remove the ambiguity.

Comment: @Tetsujin You're right that US international is probably a better compromise but I often write ^ (in latex) and having to write this via shift+6 then space, rather than just shift+6, would be quite annoying.

Comment: @DavidPostill Thanks for spotting this, I've corrected it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a custom keyboard, based on UK international but with a custom positioning of \, is an option, eg using microsoft keyboard layout creator. I found the tutorial [here](https://littletinyfish.com/create-a-new-keyboard-layout-with-the-microsoft-keyboard-layout-creator/) helpful. Also note that microsoft keyboard layout creator runs into problems when run from a filepath with spaces in, so the .exe file needs to be put into an appropriate folder (see the answer from 09/02/2015 [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.win32.programmer.international/dR5Z570hwis)).